# Solve for x: $3^{x+4} + 3*5^{x+3} = 5^{x+4} + 3^{x+3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My way:

$3^{x+4} + 3*5^{x+3} = 5^{x+4} + 3^{x+3} \\
3^{x+4} - 3^{x+3} = 5^{x+4} - 3*5^{x+3}  \\
3^{x+3}(3-3^0)=5^{x+3}(5-3) \\
3^{x+3} * 2 = 5^{x+3} * 2$

and I don't know what to do next?

Comment: Cancel the 2s and take the logarithm of both sides.

Comment: $$(3/5)^{x+3}=5^3$$ and take log

Comment: I got $x = -3$ and it was correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the same exponents appear on all terms:

$$3\cdot3^{x+3} + 3\cdot5^{x+3} = 5\cdot5^{x+3} + 3^{x+3}.$$

Simplify:

$$3^{x+3} = 5^{x+3}.$$

The only way for these two powers to be equal is with exponent $0$, hence

$$x=-3.$$

Comment: You can also work with $(5/3)^{x+3}=1$.